# Find start index and end index of substring

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like "________ _____________ occurs when a behaviour is immediately followed by the removal of an aversive ________ that increases the future frequency of the behaviour"

I want to return and array or list that has the first and last index position of each underscored area.

e.g. in my example, I'd get (0, 7, 9, 21, 101, 108)

The 6 numbers are the indexes of the start and end of the three sections of underscores - the first 'blank' starts at index 1 and ends at index 7, the second starts at position 9 and ends at 21 etc.

This is what I've done so far but I'm stuck

```
public List<int> GetPositions(string source, string searchString)
{
    List<int> ret = new List<int>();
    int len = searchString.Length;
    int start = -len;
    while (true)
    {
        start = source.IndexOf(searchString, start + len);
        if (start == -1)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ret.Add(start);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I only see two lines why should there be 6 return numbers...can you give a clearer example?

Comment: Yeah I cannot really understand what you are asking, I suggest editing your question.

Comment: are you always grabbing the words at fixed positions or can it vary which words you want to grab?  Are you looking for the same words each time?  Your question is very vague.

Comment: The 6 numbers are the indexes of the start and end of the three sections of underscores - the first 'blank' starts at index 1 and ends at index 7, the second starts at position 9 and ends at 21 etc. Does that makes sense? Thanks

Comment: @Steve - there's a space between the fist two blanks.

Comment: @Kevbo - I'm always looking for the starting and end positions of the underscored areas. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at `RegEx` and match groups, you could do what you ask in one line.

Comment: based on what you said i dont think there is an easier method other than what you are doing.  Since you need the start and end index of each occurrence you are going to have to do the looping.  Hopefully someone else will have a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple regular expression for that:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "_+");
var result = new List<int>();
foreach(Match m in matches)
{
    result.Add(m.Index);
    result.Add(m.Index + m.Length - 1);
}
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GX9MXR

If you want to avoid underscored within words you can also use `@"\b_+\b"`.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to do what you want, if you're averse to regular expressions:

```
public List<int> GetUnderscorePositions(string source)
{
   List<int> positions = new List<int>();
   bool withinUnderscore = false;

   for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {
        var c = source[i];
        if (c == '_') {
            if (withinUnderscore) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                withinUnderscore = true;
                positions.Add(i);
            }
        }
        else if (withinUnderscore) {
            withinUnderscore = false;
            positions.Add(i - 1);   
       }
    }

    return positions;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find all of these using the various overloads of string.IndexOf().

You can get the start of the first "blank" with:

```
sourceString.IndexOf('_');
```

Then the end of the first blank with:

```
sourceString.IndexOf("_ ");
```

The start of the second "blank" with:

```
sourceString.IndexOf('_', endBlank1Index + 1);
```

The end of the second "blank" with:

```
sourceString.IndexOf("_ ", startBlank2Index);
```

Rinse and repeat until no other occurrences are found.

Comment: Nice trick. An edge case here is when the last block is at the end: `"hello _____"` - in this case `"_ "` will not be found.

Comment: Good point.  I'm sure there is a way to tweak it.  I just wanted to point out it could be done using only the string library.  Also, I really like that regex answer, it's almost too simple to be true!